# Plastic SCM v. Unity Teams?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

I have used Plastic SCM for Unity development (and other development) for quite awhile now and really like it.

I notice however that Unity has brought down the pricing on Unity Teams making it free for small projects.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of Unity Teams v. Plastic SCM for both source code management and team synchronization?